# Powershell: Sending an email if output of command differs from the array of 3 strings that is expected

Tags: regex, powershell, perforce

this is what i got so far

if the command places a forth line of output then the regex shouldn't be match, but it does for me.

any ideas?

```
$From = "cody@tech.com"
$To = "cody@tech.com"
$Subject = "hello"
$Body = "body"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Attachment = "c:\checkpointlog.txt"

$RE = [regex]"(?smi)^Checkpointing to checkpoint.*^MD5 \(checkpoint.*^Rotating D:\\Perforce\\Server\\journal to journal.*?$"

$output = p4d -jc
$output | add-content c:\checkpointlog.txt

if ($output -notmatch $RE) { 
    $param = @{
        From        = $From
        To          = $To
        Subject     = $Subject
        Body        = $Body 
        SmtpServer  = $SMTPServer 
        port        = $SMTPPort 
        Usessl      = $True
        Credential  = $cred 
        Attachments = $Attachment
    }
    Send-MailMessage @param
    Write-Host 'unexpected value, email sent' 
    exit
}
else {
Write-Host 'continuing script' 

}
```

the output of a Perforce Helix Server command **p4 -jc** should always be like the following 3 lines:

```
Checkpointing to checkpoint.22... 
MD5 (checkpoint.22) = F561234wer2B8E5123456767745645616D 
Rotating D:\Perforce\Server\journal to journal.21...
```

I would like to use a regex in an if statement so that if the output doesn't match the 3 line string below then an email is sent with the log file for us to inspect.

```
Checkpointing to checkpoint.*
MD5 (checkpoint.*
Rotating D:\Perforce\Server\journal to journal.*
```

I am hoping to use a wild card * to account for the incremental number

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your **regex tries to match *multiple lines*,** and therefore **needs a *single multi-line* string as input**.
- **Capturing an external program's output returns an *array* of strings (lines)**.
- Using an *array* of string as the LHS of the `-match` operator causes PowerShell to match the regex against each string *individually*.

Therefore, **join the lines output by `p4d` with newlines to form a single multi-line string**, so that your regex can match multiple lines:

```
$output = (p4d -jc) -join "`n"
```

---

Additionally, if you want **to make sure that your regex matches the *entire* input, not just a *substring***, restructure you regex as follows:

- Remove in-line option `m` (multi-line) so that `^` and `$` truly only match the very start and end of the multi-line string
- Remove in-line option `s`, so that `.` doesn't match newlines, and match newlines explicitly with `\n` (instead of `^`).

```
$RE = '(?i)^Checkpointing to checkpoint.*\nMD5 \(checkpoint.*\nRotating D:\\Perforce\\Server\\journal to journal.*$'
```

Comment: I'm glad we found a solution, @CodyHernandez; my pleasure.

Comment: @CodyHernandez: On second thought, I think there's a simpler, more robust solution - please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

- Build (and test) your Regular Expression on a website like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PlrU8E/1)
- I suggest to use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1)

---

```
$RE = [regex]"(?smi)^Checkpointing to checkpoint.*^MD5 \(checkpoint.*^Rotating D:\\Perforce\\Server\\journal to journal.*?$"

$output = p4d -jc
$output | add-content c:\checkpointlog.txt

if ($output -notmatch $RE) { 
    $param = @{
        From        = $From
        To          = $To
        Subject     = $Subject
        Body        = $Body 
        SmtpServer  = $SMTPServer 
        port        = $SMTPPort 
        Usessl      = $True
        Credential  = $cred 
        Attachments = 'c:\checkpointlog.txt'
    }
    Send-MailMessage @param
    exit
}
```

Comment: I could only try with your above text representation, but that worked here. You are right that regex101 doesn't exactly support the PowerShell flavor, in this aspect [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) is better, but has lesser general explanations.

Comment: Thanks!, there is a new line at the end, i was thinking that had something to do with it not matching for me

Answer (score -1):

I know you wanted to use RegEx but maybe this would help?  It might not be the greatest but it should work.

```
$file='checkpointlog.txt'

$line1Expected="Checkpointing to checkpoint*"
$line2Expected="MD5 (checkpoint*"
$line3Expected="Rotating D:\Perforce\Server\journal to journal*"

$line1Actual=Get-Content($file) | Select -Index 0
$line2Actual=Get-Content($file) | Select -Index 1
$line3Actual=Get-Content($file) | Select -Index 2


if($line1Actual -like $line1Expected`
    -and $line2Actual -like $line2Expected`
    -and $line3Actual -like $line3Expected){
}else{
    echo 'send mail'
}
```

Comment: good approach, but if there is an error displayed on a forth line, this code will let it sneak through during my short test.